# Find elements in unsorted array that can be found by binary search

Tags: arrays, sorting, binary-search

For an unsorted array, I want to know the elements that can be found using binary search. Can I achieve this without actually binary searching for each of the elements?

For example here's an binary search algorithm

```
def binary_search(arr, low, high, x): 

    if high >= low: 

        mid = (high + low) // 2

        if arr[mid] == x: 
            return mid 

        elif arr[mid] > x: 
            return binary_search(arr, low, mid - 1, x) 

        else: 
            return binary_search(arr, mid + 1, high, x) 

    else: 
        return -1
```

For example my input is [3,5,4,8,7,6,10], output will be [3,5,8,10], because

```
binary_search(lst, 0,6,3)
0
binary_search(lst, 0,6,5)
1
binary_search(lst, 0,6,4)
-1
binary_search(lst, 0,6,8)
3
binary_search(lst, 0,6,7)
-1
binary_search(lst, 0,6,6)
-1
binary_search(lst, 0,6,10)
6
```

That is, only the numbers 3,5,8,10 can be found.

Comment: For an unsorted array, how can you guarantee you can find anything with binary search?

Comment: It seems like you are accumulating values that are greater than the ones that were found so far.  It could be done, but I doubt it's called "binary search"...

Comment: you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895627/can-we-use-binary-search-with-an-unsorted-array) for information